# SpringBoot + WebFlux + GraphQL - Expected source object to be an instance of 'com.example.MyObject' but instead got 'reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust'

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, spring-webflux

I am trying to implement a reactive architecture to my Spring+MongoDB+GraphQL app, have followed some tutorials on that, but whenever I return a `Publisher<Page>` from my `GraphQLQueryResolver` - I get this error:

```
2022-11-17 09:18:56.316 ERROR 14166 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] 
g.servlet.DefaultGraphQLErrorHandler     : Error executing query 
(ExceptionWhileDataFetching): Exception while fetching data (/getPages/id) : Expected 
source object to be an instance of 'com.example.jobscraperspringserver.types.Page' but 
instead got 'reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust'
```

I've played with the returned object (tried `Flux<Page>`, `Publisher<List<Page>>` and other configurations) as well as a type in the `schema.graphqls`, but none of them work. Besides, that's what supposed to be working in the majority of tutorials as well as some other SO issues, so I suppose that's either a bug somewhere in my code or an architectural flaw (i.e. some faulty dependency that doesn't support the type convertion).

Here is my code:

**PageQuery.java**

```
@Component
public class PageQuery implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
    @Autowired
    PageService pageService;

    public Publisher<Page> getPages() {
        return pageService.getPages();
    }
}
```

**PageService.java**

```
@Service
public class PageService {

    public Flux<Page> getPages() {
        return Flux.just(new Page(12));
    }

}
```

**schema.graphqls**

```
type Page {
    id: Int!
    host: String
}

type Query {
    getPages: Page
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
...

<dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- GraphQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- GraphQL subscriptions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MongoDB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-reactivestreams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JWT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- WebFlux -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

...
```

**UPDATE**

Apparently `com.graphql-java` doesn't handle `WebFlux`, so I've replaced

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-M3</version>
</dependency>
```

but now I am getting a `null` instead of a `Page`...

**UPDATE 2**
I've also tried the

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>11.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphql-kickstart-spring-webflux</artifactId>
  <version>11.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

but got the same result. I figured it supports a `CompletableFuture<List<Page>>`, but this is still blocking and I've seen multiple tutorials on returning `Mono/Flux` from a graphql resolver...

**UPDATE 3**
I've updated the all the Spring modules' versions to `2.6.3` to be consistent and I've also removed the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency, as the `spring-boot-starter-webflux` should be sufficient; but neither of those fixes have solved my issue.

**UPDATE 4**
This is the entity I want to return wrapped in a `Flux`:

```
@Document("pages")
public class Page {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String host;
    private String path;
    private String jobAnchorSelector;
    private String jobLinkContains;
    private int numberOfPages;
    private int interval;
    private Date lastScrapePerformed;
    private String userUuid;

    public Page() {
    }

    public Page(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getJobAnchorSelector() {
        return jobAnchorSelector;
    }

    public void setJobAnchorSelector(String jobAnchorSelector) {
        this.jobAnchorSelector = jobAnchorSelector;
    }

    public String getJobLinkContains() {
        return jobLinkContains;
    }

    public void setJobLinkContains(String jobLinkContains) {
        this.jobLinkContains = jobLinkContains;
    }

    public int getNumberOfPages() {
        return numberOfPages;
    }

    public void setNumberOfPages(int numberOfPages) {
        this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Page [" + host + path + "]";
    }

    public int getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    public void setInterval(int interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public Date getLastScrapePerformed() {
        return lastScrapePerformed;
    }

    public void setLastScrapePerformed(Date lastScrapePerformed) {
        this.lastScrapePerformed = lastScrapePerformed;
    }

    public String getUserUuid() {
        return userUuid;
    }

    public void setUserUuid(String userUuid) {
        this.userUuid = userUuid;
    }
}
```

It's a `MongoDB` document and I'm using a `ReactiveMongoRepository` to fetch that, however for the sake of simplifying this issue I was trying to return just a `Flux.just(new Page(2))`.

Comment: Have you also tried using Mono<Page>?

Comment: @ouid Yes I did, same result

Comment: Maybe you could try to use `com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter` instead of `com.graphql-java:*` to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @ouid tried that, same exception is being thrown..

Comment: You need `spring-boot-starter-webflux` not `spring-boot-starter-web` as the latter is blocking (using the servlet API where the former is reactive (you appear to have both, use one or the other not both). Another thing is your dependencies are a mess and bound for trouble you are mixing, at least 3 versions of Spring Boot modules, never do that as that will lead to issues. Finally I don't really get all the mixture of versions and why not simply use `spring-boot-starter-graphql` instead of the experimental (and thus old) stuff.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for noticing, but removing the `spring-boot-starter-web` did not change anything, neither did making the spring modules' versions consistent as `2.6.3`. There is no mixture of graphql dependencies, I just have tried all the existing ones, one by one, but neither of them got me to where I want to be...

Comment: Still you didn't use the `spring-boot-starter-graphql` bit some mix of 3rd party dependencies. I would strongly suggest to remove all GraphQL dependencies and only add `spring-boot-starter-graphql` and retry (and without the `spring-boot-starter-web`.). Remove the `version` tag from the official `org.springframework.boot` dependencies. As you already have webflux you don't need the `reactor-core` dependency, you also don't need the security dependencies as you already have `spring-boot-starter-security`. Still looks like a dependency thing due to all the stuff in there.

Comment: Hello, could you add your Page POJO?

Comment: @JulioCésarEstravis I've added an update

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you're using Spring Boot, I would recommend that you use `spring-boot-starter-graphql` instead of `graphql-spring-boot-starter`, and you need to add `spring-boot-starter-webflux` to implement reactive data fetchers. Also if you want to return `Flux`, you should define returned type as an array in the schema (e.g. `getPages: [Page!]!`), otherwise, you should return `Mono`.

This will allow you to implement your query like this:

```
@Controller
public class PageController {

    // ...
    
    @QueryMapping 
    public Flux<Page> getPages() {
        return pageService.getPages();
    }
}
```

But you should note that by default `Mono` and `Flux` are adapted to a `CompletableFuture` where `Flux` values are aggregated and turned into a `List`. If you want to stream responses, then you should also use GraphQL subscription instead of a query.

Comment: Right, I didn't know that, thanks for the implementation details.. In this case I'll just stick with returning a `CompletableFuture` for `Queries`/`Mutations` (and btw, I do have a `Subscription` in this proj).